# Value of one of my axis does not change when I read the data of my armature

Tags: armature, bones

I want to read the data of my armature (specifically each bone) but the problem is the value of one of my axis does not change

This is a part of my code

```
foot_L = bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['foot.L']

for iteration in range(1,15):
 
        foot_L.bone.select = True
        print("foot_L.location =", foot_L.location)
```

Comment: In a comment to an answer you say, in effect, that the code snippet in your question doesn't reflect the code that's showing the problem.  Please include a complete blend file that does show the problem, or nobody will be able to help you. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the position of the bones as they appear in *pose* mode, here is the loop for your print.

```py
for bone in bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones:
    print(f'{bone.name}.location = {bone.location}')
```

If you want the position of the bones as they appear in *edit* mode, you don't want to use the object, but rather the armature, and you need to print locations for both head and tail:

```py
for bone in bpy.data.armatures['metarig'].bones:
    print(f'{bone.name}')
    print(f'\t head = ({bone.head[0]:5.2f}, {bone.head[1]:5.2f}, {bone.head[2]:5.2f})')
    print(f'\t tail = ({bone.rail[0]:5.2f}, {bone.tail[1]:5.2f}, {bone.tail[2]:5.2f})')
```

Although you might want to make the print of the positions prettier.

Comment: this was a sample of my code for one bone but with this command, I have not got the correct answer I'm looking for a command for this issue

Comment: I understand you
I meant you use the .location command like me in your code but these command does not return a correct value to me
for more explanation, I can say this: I need the location of some bones which are not translated but their position changes because of the effect of the other bones 
in my model, I just rotate and translate some bones, and others are influenced by rotated and translated bones