# How can I get the global coordinates of joints or bones of a skeleton during animation?

Tags: coordinates

I want to get the coordinates of joints of a skeleton. The following is the main code I used.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
obj_bone = bpy.context.object.data.bones
for f in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end):
  scene.frame_set(f)
  verts = [obj.matrix_world @ obj_bone[i].head_local for i in range(31)]
```

But the coordinates of joints are the same between frames, seems the obj_bone only gets the coordinates in EDIT mode, how to get coordinates for all frames?

Comment: See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240353/value-of-one-of-my-axis-does-not-change-when-i-read-the-data-of-my-armature/240386#240386) for code; but the summary is that if you look at the armature's `.pose.bones` instead of `.data.bones` you get the position of the bones in pose mode.

Comment: Thanks marty. I tried pose.bones[i].head, but this coordinates are relative to its parent, unlike data.bones, it has attribute "head_local", which is relative to the armature, thus I can use "obj.matrix_world @ obj_bone[i].head_local" to get the world coordinates of bones. How to go from pose.bones[i].head coordinates to world coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. According to marty's comment, I use pose.bones instead of data.bones and the world coordinates of bones are calculated as follows:

```
obj = bpy.context.object
pb = obj.pose.bones["Neck1"]
obj.matrix_world @ pb.matrix @ pb.location
```

more details see [How to get posebone global location](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35982/how-to-get-posebone-global-location)